# Excel VBA to populate parent child drop down source from sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have sheet with data like below and 2 combo boxes in user form with the names ComboBox1(parent) and ComboBox2(child)

```
Parent |Child
-------|------
  A    |   1
  A    |   2
  A    |   3
  X    |   100
  X    |   101
  X    |   102
```

With below code I took distinct values into Parent combo.

```
Dim s As String, r As Integer, nr As Integer, wr, v
Set wr = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")
nr = wr.Rows.Count
With ComboBox1
 .Clear
 For r = 1 To nr
  v = wr(r, 1)
  If InStr(s, v & ",") = 0 Then
   s = s & v & ","
   .AddItem (v)
  End If
 Next
End With
```

I am looking help to populate child combo based on selected value in Parent combo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use a `Dictionary` to remember which entries in ComboBox1 already exists because you can easily test with `dict.Exists(NewItem)`.

And the Data for ComboBox2 needs to automatically re-initialize on the `ComboBox1_Change` event.

*Note that you should use more descriptive variable names `s, r, nr, wr, v` are pretty meaningless, while names like `ComboRange1` or `NewItem` are pretty good readable for humans. Makes your life much easier and results in less errors.*

```
Option Explicit

Sub InitComboBox1()
    Dim ComboRange1 As Range
    Set ComboRange1 = Sheet1.Range("A1", Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

    ComboBox1.Clear

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To ComboRange1.Rows.Count
        Dim NewItem As String
        NewItem = ComboRange1.Cells(i, 1).Text

        If Not dict.Exists(NewItem) Then
            dict.Add NewItem, 0
            ComboBox1.AddItem NewItem
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim ComboRange2 As Range
    Set ComboRange2 = Sheet1.Range("A1", Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Resize(ColumnSize:=2)

    ComboBox2.Clear

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To ComboRange2.Rows.Count
        If ComboRange2.Cells(i, 1).Text = ComboBox1.Value Then
            Dim NewItem As String
            NewItem = ComboRange2.Cells(i, 2).Text

            If Not dict.Exists(NewItem) Then
                dict.Add NewItem, 0
                ComboBox2.AddItem NewItem
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```